# Grouped quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management, bundled-product, grouped-products, quantity

I have a magento 1.9.1.0 platform and need something to group some quantities.
The site sell products on set and I have two grouped products ProductA (100pcs/set) and ProductB (50pcs/set). Now if a customer want to order 1xProductA (100pcs/set) than I need the quantity for ProductB to be 2xProductB or 2xProductA and the quantity for ProductB should be 4.
Could someone help me or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Use bundled product instead of grouped product, and create it with dynamic pricing like this:

- **Option A**: Type "Checkbox", Required

  - Selection: ProductA, Default Qty 100
- **Option B**: Type "Checkbox", Required

  - Selection: ProductB, Default Qty 50

Now the customer will not have any possibility to configure the bundle, he just can add the whole bundle to the cart. With bundle qty 1, they'll get 100xA and 50xB, with bundle qty 2, they'll get 200xA and 100xB and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Are they two separate skus? Because you could set up something like a configurable inventory item. Where you have 1 product set at description of 50pcs and the other at 100pcs. Then when a customer clicks on the product, they can then select from a drop down menu of which pcs count they want.  See this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product and then set up an attribute for "pcs" count.

Comment: Yes, they are two separate sku. I can't use configurable product because first I must enter a lot of variants because the stock is big and secondly the customers can be careless and they don't read everything. The thing is that they, now are able to order 2xProductA(total 200pcs) and just 1xProductB(total 50pcs) which is not good for our company. The pcs must be equal for both product. I think I need some jquery for auto updating the quantity for the ProductB and for the customer just to be able to enter the quantity for ProductB